# vim indentation braces inside parentheses

Tags: c++, vim, auto-indent

In vim (eg 7.3), how can I use/modify the `cindent` or `smartindent` options, or otherwise augment my `.vimrc`, in order to automatically indent curly braces inside open parentheses to align to the first "word" (defined later) directly preceding the opening `(`?

The `fN` option seems promising, but appears to be overridden by the `(N` option when inside open parentheses. From [`:help cinoptions-values`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/indent.html#cinoptions-values):

```
fN    Place the first opening brace of a function or other block in
      column N.  This applies only for an opening brace that is not
      inside other braces and is at the start of the line.  What comes
      after the brace is put relative to this brace.  (default 0).

        cino=           cino=f.5s       cino=f1s
          func()          func()          func()
          {                 {                 {
              int foo;          int foo;          int foo;
```

Current behavior:

```
func (// no closing ) 
      // (N behavior, here N=0      
      {    // (N behavior overrides fN ?
        int foo; // >N behavior, here N=2
```

while I wish for:

```
func (// no closing )   
      // (N behavior as before   
{ // desired behavior
  int foo; // >N behavior still works
```

What I am asking for is *different* from `fN` because `fN` aligns to the prevailing indent, and I want to align to any C++ `nested-name-specifier` that directly precedes the opening `(`, like

```
code; f::g<T> (         instead of         code; f::g<T> (
      {                                    {
```

If there is no `nested-name-specifier`, I'd like it to match the `(` itself. Perhaps matching a `nested-name-specifier` is too complicated, or maybe there is another part of the grammer this is more appropriate for this scenario. Anyway, for my typical use case, I think I'd be satisfied if the `{` aligns with the first nonwhitespace character of the maximal sequence of characters to the left of the innermost unclosed `(`, inclusive, that does not contain any semicolons or left curly braces `}`.

By the way, I arrived at this when trying to autoindent various `std::for_each(b,e,[]{});` constructs in vim7.3. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try `set nocindent`, that worked for me - but i have also smartident and autoindent turned on

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that any of the {auto,smart,c}indent features could be finagled to do what you want. I made up a mapping which might give some inspiration:

```
inoremap ({ <esc>T<space>y0A<space>(<cr><esc>pVr<space>A{
```

Downsides are that you may need to do something smarter than 'T' to get back to the beginning of the last identifier (you could use '?' with a regex), that it trashes your default register, and that if your identifier before the paren is at the start of the line you have to do '({' yourself. The notion is to jump back to just before the identifier, copy to the beginning of the line, paste that to the next line, and replace every character with a space.

Good luck!